# css declaration in Angular 5.1.3

Tags: css, angular, angular-cli, declaration

When I'm adding my extra list of  css in index.html that time it(Template) works fine but whenever I'm adding same list of css in angular-cli.json that time css comes with junks(I meant not having proper Template) in css please tell me how to resolve it.See below

This works fine:

```
<link href="assets/css/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Pretty Photo CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Swiper Slider CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/swiper.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Custom Main StyleSheet CSS -->
  <link href="assets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Color CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/color-2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Typography StyleSheet CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/typography-02.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Responsive CSS -->
  <link href="assets/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This is not working in my angular-cli.json

```
 "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "assets/css/flexslider.css",
        "assets/css/prettyPhoto.css",
        "assets/css/swiper.css",
        "assets/style.css",
        "assets/css/color-2.css",
        "assets/css/typography-02.css",
        "assets/css/responsive.css"
      ],
```

Comment: Any error or something?

Comment: Can you post your directory structure?

Comment: try to add "." before the "assets" and rebuild your app

Comment: I think you just need your paths corrected -> `"../src/assets/STUFF"`

Comment: Having no error @ValaKhosravi

Comment: That didn't work @RoweldeGuzman

Comment: That didn't work  @ChrisW.

Comment: sorry may answer is incomplete my bad,
try to add "./" before the "assets" and rebuild your app. this may work

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "./assets/css/flexslider.css",
        "./assets/css/prettyPhoto.css",
        "./assets/css/swiper.css",
        "./assets/style.css",
        "./assets/css/color-2.css",
        "./assets/css/typography-02.css",
        "./assets/css/responsive.css"
]
```